# Поиск всех значений в тексте

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

есть текст `[a]какой то текст[/a] еще куча какого то текста, [a]какой то текст[/a]`
есть регулярка `/(\[a.+\/a\])/` если текст без переноса строки, то находит начиная от [a] заканчивая [/a], то есть включая не нуныйй текст, который не обнимается [a][/a]
как найти весть текст который обнимаются этим: [a][/a]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте модификатор `s` и нежадный квантификатор `*?`:

```
'~\[a].*?\[/a]~s'
```

Или

```
'~\[a][\s\S]*?\[/a]~'
```

См. [демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/XHPY04/2). Так как `[\s\S]` находит любой символ по умолчанию, модификатор `s` не нужен.

**Подробности**

- `\[a]` - `[a]`
- `.*?` / `[\s\S]*?` - любые 0 и более символов, но как можно меньше, до первого вхождения...
- `\[/a]` - `[/a]`.

Comment: Огромное СПАСИБО!!! Порекомендуете литературу почитать по этой теме?

Comment: Прошу сразу тапками не бросать, php не знаю, но для выбора группы еще модно использовать круглые скобки, для выделения группы, исключая символы ограничения `\[a](.*?)\[/a]` или `\[a]([\s\S]*?)\[/a]`, это верно?

Comment: @PotroNik Верно, `if (preg_match_all('~\[a](.*?)\[/a]~s', $s, $matches)) {
   print_r($matches[1]);
}` [вернёт](https://3v4l.org/MRKpJ) `[ 'какой-то \nтекст', 'какого-то текста\n']`

Comment: @MaximLyubitelev [Синтаксис регулярных выражений](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php) для начала. А ещё на английском https://regexone.com/ и http://regular-expressions.info. Для продвинутых - http://rexegg.com.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew спасибо =)